# Sudo with Sidekick

Tags: terminal, permission, sudo

[Sidekick](http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/) is a helpful little tool which adjusts the system settings based on geographical location.

I added an action which will execute a `sudo` command-line command. The problem is that the Terminal pops up and asks me for the password. Is there a way to allow Sidekick to execute `sudo` without asking for a password?

Comment: The real question is, do you really want to? `sudo` requires a password after regular intervals for a good reason. http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudo.man.html

Comment: I want to enable and disable some sharing settings: turning file, web sharing and remote management on and off. This is possible without a password anyways via System Preferences. Sadly this is not supported by AppleScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable password prompt when calling sudo in combination with certain commands by editing the sudoers file. This is done by opening a terminal and running `sudo visudo`. You have to add the follwing lines

```
Cmnd_Alias SIDEKICK_CMDS = /full/path/to/the/command1,  /full/path/to/the/command2

yourUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SIDEKICK_CMDS
```

Be careful with this, as it may lead to security risks.  It enables anyone logged in  with your account ( so not just sidekick) to run the  commands in the list without a password prompt.

For a full description of the `sudoers` options check the manpage : `man sudoers`